# Windows and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I am trying to run Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 both on the same machine. But when I first installed Ubuntu, I was unable to boot Windows 7. There was an error coming up saying: `disk read error`. Later I fixed it using fixboot and got my Windows 7 back, and now I'm unable to boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Check if secure boot was enabled when you did boot-repair.

You may have to disable/enable secure boot (check BIOS). In my experience with boot-repair, I had to check **use EFI partition** to get dual boot working.

More info at [Boot-Repair - Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: i tried my bios for secure boot, i couldnt find that option. i will try this EFI partition.